# Graph multiple lines in Python (one line per categorie) in one dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataframe where I want to create a line graph. I want one line per category and on the x-axis I want the date, and on the y-axis the 12MKG. I don’t know how to put labels on the lines and make the lines different colours per category.

So far I have tried:

```
plt.plot(df['date'], datatoplot['12MKG'])
```

| date | categorie | 12MKG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | cat1 | 0.9836956 |
| 202002 | cat1 | 0.9836956 |
| 202003 | cat1 | 0.9831461 |
| 202004 | cat1 | 0.97206706 |
| 202005 | cat1 | 0.9698492 |
| 202006 | cat1 | 0.97630334 |
| 202007 | cat1 | 0.9787234 |
| 202008 | cat1 | 0.9810606 |
| 202009 | cat1 | 0.9825784 |
| 202010 | cat1 | 0.98165137 |
| 202011 | cat1 | 0.9768116 |
| 202012 | cat1 | 0.96666664 |
| 202101 | cat1 | 0.9655172 |
| 202102 | cat1 | 0.95214105 |
| 202103 | cat1 | 0.93721974 |
| 202104 | cat1 | 0.9419087 |
| 202105 | cat1 | 0.93158954 |
| 202106 | cat1 | 0.9189189 |
| 202107 | cat1 | 0.9144603 |
| 202001 | cat2 | 0.3118644 |
| 202002 | cat2 | 0.3006993 |
| 202003 | cat2 | 0.3017544 |
| 202004 | cat2 | 0.29433963 |
| 202005 | cat2 | 0.3030303 |
| 202006 | cat2 | 0.30483273 |
| 202007 | cat2 | 0.33206108 |
| 202008 | cat2 | 0.33730158 |
| 202009 | cat2 | 0.344 |
| 202010 | cat2 | 0.34008098 |
| 202011 | cat2 | 0.34051725 |
| 202012 | cat2 | 0.3224299 |
| 202101 | cat2 | 0.33027524 |
| 202102 | cat2 | 0.3187773 |
| 202103 | cat2 | 0.29338843 |
| 202104 | cat2 | 0.28458497 |
| 202105 | cat2 | 0.2804878 |
| 202106 | cat2 | 0.2804878 |
| 202107 | cat2 | 0.2631579 |

Comment: Re "dataframe": Does that imply [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) (`DataFrame`)?

Comment: What is *"12MKG*"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen it's a 12 month rolling average on some KPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use colormap to get different colors for each line and df.loc to filter each category

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = set(df['categorie'].values)
colors = pl.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(labels)))
for key, color in zip(labels, range(len(labels))):
    data_x = df.loc[df['categorie']==key]['date']
    data_y = df.loc[df['categorie']==key]['12MKG']
    plt.plot(data_x, data_y, color=colors[color], label=key)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

See here for more details on [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, 
P.S. after len(labels)) there is missing 1 closing bracket, and the line below there are 2 closing brackets missing. just typing it for completeness

Comment: Do you know how I could change line thickness based on a fourth column with values between 20 and 800?

Comment: Better ask new question as its easier to search for others if they will have the same issue and its harder to properly format multi line code in comments. Also I dont know what's in the 4 column so it's hard to say what will be the best approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634047/line-thickness-in-pyplot-graph-based-on-dataframe-column here is the link to the new question if you are interested

Comment: Nowakoski, do you know why the colors aren't alphabetically coloured? i have cat1 being red, and cat2 blue, and so on. they aren't from blue to red according to the alphabet.

Comment: This is based on how colormap works its not alphabetical order [see docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). You can see there that jet changes from blue to red

Comment: What is "cmap"? Do you mean "colormap"? Or something else? Is it literal or not? Can you link to documentation? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68541201/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks I linked to tutorial from official matplotilb site. Cmap is also used as shortcut in those docs that's why I used it. I changed it to be more specific and obvious