# Line thickness in pyplot graph based on a dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

First, the dataframe:

| date | categorie | 12MKG | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | cat1 | 0.8947368 | 38.0 |
| 202002 | cat1 | 0.8695652 | 46.0 |
| 202003 | cat1 | 0.8913044 | 46.0 |
| 202004 | cat1 | 0.88372093 | 43.0 |
| 202005 | cat1 | 0.8913044 | 46.0 |
| 202006 | cat1 | 0.8888889 | 45.0 |
| 202007 | cat1 | 0.8780488 | 41.0 |
| 202008 | cat1 | 0.925 | 40.0 |
| 202009 | cat1 | 0.8684211 | 38.0 |
| 202010 | cat1 | 0.76744187 | 43.0 |
| 202011 | cat1 | 0.7111111 | 45.0 |
| 202012 | cat1 | 0.6888889 | 45.0 |
| 202101 | cat1 | 0.7083333 | 48.0 |
| 202102 | cat1 | 0.73333335 | 45.0 |
| 202103 | cat1 | 0.74 | 50.0 |
| 202104 | cat1 | 0.71428573 | 56.0 |
| 202105 | cat1 | 0.7241379 | 58.0 |
| 202106 | cat1 | 0.7258065 | 62.0 |
| 202107 | cat1 | 0.71875 | 64.0 |
| 202001 | cat2 | 0.6244344 | 221.0 |
| 202002 | cat2 | 0.6136364 | 220.0 |
| 202003 | cat2 | 0.61085975 | 221.0 |
| 202004 | cat2 | 0.6028708 | 209.0 |
| 202005 | cat2 | 0.63013697 | 219.0 |
| 202006 | cat2 | 0.6034483 | 232.0 |
| 202007 | cat2 | 0.5914894 | 235.0 |
| 202008 | cat2 | 0.59322035 | 236.0 |
| 202009 | cat2 | 0.6008584 | 233.0 |
| 202010 | cat2 | 0.5903614 | 249.0 |
| 202011 | cat2 | 0.5836735 | 245.0 |
| 202012 | cat2 | 0.57377046 | 244.0 |
| 202101 | cat2 | 0.5795918 | 245.0 |
| 202102 | cat2 | 0.56666666 | 270.0 |
| 202103 | cat2 | 0.557971 | 276.0 |
| 202104 | cat2 | 0.548951 | 286.0 |
| 202105 | cat2 | 0.5270758 | 277.0 |
| 202106 | cat2 | 0.53985506 | 276.0 |
| 202107 | cat2 | 0.53488374 | 258.0 |
| 202001 | cat3 | 0.426 | 500.0 |
| 202002 | cat3 | 0.40963855 | 498.0 |
| 202003 | cat3 | 0.40365112 | 493.0 |
| 202004 | cat3 | 0.41129032 | 496.0 |
| 202005 | cat3 | 0.4144869 | 497.0 |
| 202006 | cat3 | 0.4 | 500.0 |
| 202007 | cat3 | 0.39478958 | 499.0 |
| 202008 | cat3 | 0.4137255 | 510.0 |
| 202009 | cat3 | 0.4035433 | 508.0 |

And I want to create a line graph. I want one line per category and on the x-axis I want the date, and on the y-axis the 12MKG. I also want every line to have a different colour, which is what I have managed so far (with support from @Piotr Nowakowski).

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = set(df['categorie'].values)
colors = pl.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(labels)))
for key, color in zip(labels, range(len(labels))):
    data_x = df.loc[df['categorie']==key]['date']
    data_y = df.loc[df['categorie']==key]['12MKG']
    plt.plot(data_x, data_y, color=colors[color], label=key)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Now I want the lines in the graph to have different thickness, where the thickness increases with the amount column. The line thickness can either vary based on amount for each date, or per line one thickness based on the last amount value, in this case based on date == 202107.

Comment: Re "dataframe": Does that imply [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) (`DataFrame`)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen In this case it was a pandas dataframe, but this was not mentioned before, because I was willing to change my dataframe to a pyspark dataframe if somebody preferred to make the solution work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = set(df['categorie'].values)
colors = pl.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(labels)))
width_lines = df.amount.values
for key, color, width in zip(labels, range(len(labels)), width_lines):
    data_x = df.loc[df['categorie']==key]['date']
    data_y = df.loc[df['categorie']==key]['12MKG']
    width = df.loc[df['categorie']==key]['amount']
    width = sum(width)
    plt.plot(data_x, data_y, color=colors[color], label=key, linewidth=width/100)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I'm not sure what the range of the amount values is. If simple division doesn't match your case, you can try to first aggregate all values and then adjust the range.